# using the python shell like VRAM (drawing using print)

Tags: python, shell, drawing, screen

I'm trying to make a VERY basic interface in the python shell that keeps the current information on the screen but also draws a little "...." that increases in size and then starts over once it gets to a certain size. A simple "this program is in progress" type thing.

I've got something that works, by having the screen saved in a list of strings then printing the elements line by line (hence the vram reference in the title) but the screen occasionally blinks. Is this just a limitation of using print in this manner? Is there a way to reducing the blinking (drawing less often maybe)? Is there a better way to do this that doesn't involve learning to make a full on GUI?

This is my first question asked on stackoverflow, so forgive me if i broke any question asking taboos.

EDIT:
I just realized I could save redraws by only clearing the screen when i need to make the dots go away, and just add a "." to my currently printed screen otherwise. Are there any other solutions?

Heres the example code:

```
import os
import time
ts = 0
n = ""
m = "."
vram = ["This is the first line","This is the second line","This is the third line","This is the fourth line","This is the fifth element","This is the sixth line"]
while True:
    if((time.time()-ts)>.4): #redraw every .4 seconds
        os.system('cls')
        if (len(n)>5):
            n = "."
        for item in vram:
            print (item)
        print ("hmmm so many lines"+n)
        n+=m
        ts = time.time()
```

Comment: It's possible for you to share your updated code by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't replicate your issue (I tried on Linux), but you may change some things.

You are unnecessarily calculating the time between each step. A **time.sleep** is enough and more optimized (not to say also cleaner) than a custom made **ts check**.

Also, in the length check, don't recreate a string, just reference the **m** var you created before.

```
import os
import time
n = ''
m = '.'
vram = ['This is the first line',
        'This is the second line',
        'This is the third line',
        'This is the fourth line',
        'This is the fifth element',
        'This is the sixth line']
while True:
    time.sleep(.4) # Sleep for.4 seconds and redraw
    os.system('cls')
    for item in vram:
        print (item)
    if len(n)>5:
        n=m 
    print ('hmmm so many lines'+n)
    n+=m
```

Let me know if this made any difference.